# Visual Studio 2022 mac - Node.js is required to build and run this project

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-2022

In a client cs-project I get on build the following error:

**Error: Node.js is required to build and run this project.**

I have installed node via nvm on my mac

```
which node
```

returns /Users/***/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node

I use zsh, in my .zshrc file there are these lines:

```
ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

It seems like VS for mac is not accessing my zsh profile

build error:

```
Target NpmInstall:
    node --version
    /var/folders/rl/kb1_zj0j2xz8bbx8lj6z59y40000gn/T/MSBuildTempkinglycodes/tmp16d8f938bd884455879b344a63bd9566.exec.cmd: line 2: node: command not found
    /Users/***/Work/Dev/CS/***/src/***.Web/***.Web.csproj(41,5): warning MSB3073: The command "node --version" exited with code 127.
```

I also tried to set a symlink to the original node path
the symlink was set in

/usr/local/bin/node

(as the destination location, as I read on the internet, that this path would be found by VS 2022 for mac)

The symlink is working fine.

But now I get the following error:

```
Error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127. (MSB3073)
```

When I use this workaround, it works:
Open default terminal "iTerm" and execute this command:
`open -n "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"`

This takes the Path from the zsh profile, but does anyone know, how to set this to open the App from Finder or Dock?

Or how can I solve this issue and setup VS correctly?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a symlink to the original npm path, just as you would with node.

```
ln -s $(which npm) /usr/local/bin/npm
```